# How to run same db folder

Tags: mongodb

I am running `mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1` in console
and everything is fine. It uses by standard the `C:\data\db` folder.
But after I reload my computer and try same command it throws an error.

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1
2018-05-18T10:53:45.491+0300 I CONTROL  [main]
2018-05-18T10:53:45.491+0300 W CONTROL  [main] 32-bit servers don't have journal
ing enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
2018-05-18T10:53:45.491+0300 I CONTROL  [main]
2018-05-18T10:53:45.491+0300 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update
is not installed, will zero-out data files
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2
396 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 32-bit host=yaposhytiil-ara
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows Vis
ta/Windows Server 2008
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.20
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a7a144f40b7
0bfe290906eb33ff2714933544af8
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: i386
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: i386
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { en
gine: "mmapv1" } }
2018-05-18T10:53:45.506+0300 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdow
n - C:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.
2018-05-18T10:53:45.528+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **************
Unclean shutdown detected.
Please visit http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for recovery instructions.
*************
2018-05-18T10:53:45.531+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndList
en: 12596 old lock file, terminating
2018-05-18T10:53:45.532+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

As I understand it's locks the data from access.
I wouldn't waste your time, but I didn't know how to google it...
Is it because of 32bit Windows, or some user access settings, or I have to repair/delete db folder every time?

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: This means that the mongod instance was not shutdown properly. If you are not concerned about data loss, you can just remove the mongod.lock file in your C:\data\db folder

Comment: Do you have any explanation for: `Detected unclean shutdow
n - C:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.`?

Comment: You can also repair the current database by running mongod --repair as suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)

Comment: @AmanB Please don't engage the off-topic question. It should be migrated to the correct site, and the OP always has the option to take it there directly themselves.